# Extract Data from a Data table to a text file in JPA

Tags: sql, request

I'm working on data manipulation and my order is to extract all the content of a table into a text file ! I have already implemented this but apprently, I have commited a mistake while creating the request :

```
 public void extractDonneesFichierPlat(){
    TypedQuery<NotificationCnavOP> query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'C:\\Test.txt' FROM NotificationCnavOP", NotificationCnavOP.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use "select * into outfile..." syntax in JPQL which is a separate query language different than SQL. If you want to execute native SQL queries in JPA you must use `entityManager.createNativeQuery()` method.
But still it is not possible to execute such 'bulk manipulation' query using this method.
The only solution I can think of is to use JDBC instead of JPA and execute:

```
    Object o = entityManager.getDelegate();
    System.out.println(o.getClass()); //prints the object class
    // in my case it is org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl
    SessionImpl s = (SessionImpl)o;
    Connection c = s.connection();
    try {    
        Statement stmt = c.createStatement();
        stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'C:/Test.txt' FROM NotificationCnavOP");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The actual implementation of `Session` depends on the provider. In the case of Hibernate it is `org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl`.

For newer versions of Hibernate it is `org.hibernate.Session` and it doesn't have the `connection()` method.  So, you should try:

```
    Object o = entityManager.getDelegate();
    Session s = (Session)o;

    s.doWork(connection -> {
        try {    
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'C:/Test2.txt' FROM NotificationCnavOP");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

Both versions work in Hibernate 4.

Comment: The problem is that there isn't the method connection on session, what is the good import for object Session ? I'm in java 8 !

Comment: The actual implementation depends on your JPA provider - I edited the code. Use o.getClass() to check your implementation.